# How to list items in Orchard container?

Tags: orchardcms

In my Orchard site, there is a content type named Product.  It has the parts Container and Routable.  Products can contain a content type named ProductFeature.

I have overrode the view Content-Product.cshtml to modify the html when browsing to the Route url.
**Within this view, how can I get a list of all ProductFeature's the Product contains?**

This post shows how to do this for a blog Widget.
http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/03/27/taking-over-list-rendering-in-orchard.aspx

I'm having a hard time finding how to do this in the Product's content view.  The code from the above example throws a null exception error, so the model structure must be different.  I I tried looking at the model using Shape Tracing or debugging in Visual Studio, but couldn't find the contained items.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am attempting to do the same thing and cannot understand Bertrand Le Roy's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make sure your placement.info includes the container part, then your list of features should already being displayed.

Comment: I want to be able to access the contained items from with in the top level view.  Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You can query the content manager for CommonPartRecord where the container is your content item.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy can you provide an example of the query you mentioned in your comment above? Is this something that can be done within an alternate view of the Content Type that has the Container content part?

Comment: ```contentManager.Query<CommonPart, CommonPartRecord>().Where(c => c.Container.Id == theIdOfYourContainer).List()```

Comment: I assume this query would have to made in the driver of a custom module. Is that right?

Comment: The code in placement.info would look something like this:
`<Match ContentType="Product"><Place Parts_Container_Contained="Content:10"/></Match>`

Answer (score 2):

There are two options that I use (I know Bertrand will call them ugly and unnecessary as he has worked hard to give us many other tools, but if you either haven't grasped the full beauty of Orchard and how ingenious it is, you need these hacks.)

So here are 2:

1. Create a partial view `Parts.Container.Contained-YourContentTypeName.cshtml`

   inside:

   ```
   @foreach (var p in Model.List.Items)
   {
      // regular content parts, Title and Body
      string title = p.ContentItem.TitlePart.Title;
      string body = p.ContentItem.BodyPart.Text;

      // Your custome content parts
      string something = p.ContentItem.YourContentPartName.YourContentPartFieldName.Value;
   }
   ```
2. in `Content-YourContentTypeName.cshtml`:

   ```
   var yourList = Model.Content.Items[1].List.Items;
   ```

At least it is `Items[1]` in my case, you can check with shape tracing in model where the list is. And from here on everything is the same as 1).

Hope it helps someone who stumbles upon tis thread, looking for this solution like I did few weeks back.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Zoran's answer, if you don't want to hard-code the position of Container in the Items list you can use LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> items = Model.Content.Items;
var container = (from item in items
                 where (item.ContentPart.PartDefinition.Name == "ContainerPart")
                 select item).ElementAt(0);
```

...

```
@Display(container.List.Items)
```